# Setting one to many relationship in EF fluent mapping

Tags: entity-framework

I've two classes like this,

```
public class Post
{
   public int Id { get; set; }

   public virtual Category Category { get; set; }
}

public class Category
{
   public int Id { get; set; }

   public virtual IList<Post> Posts { get; set; }
}
```

**BlogDbContext.cs**

**OnModelCreating method:**

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Post>()
                  .HasRequired(x => x.Category)
                  .WithMany(x => x.Posts)
                  .HasForeignKey(x => x.Id);
```

On running the application I'm getting the below error.

**Post_Category_Source: : Multiplicity is not valid in Role 'Post_Category_Source' in relationship 'Post_Category'. Because the Dependent Role refers to the key properties, the upper bound of the multiplicity of the Dependent Role must be '1'.**

Any help will be really appreciated.

Comment: What did you use `HasForeignKey` for?  I don't see a foreign key defined in your POCOs.

Comment: Is it mandatory? I already have a property called Category in Post class, do I need CategoryId also?

Comment: @Mark Of course you do. One-to-many always at least requires a foreign key field in the database. If you make it part of the model by using `HasForeignKey` you also need it in the model.

Comment: Thanks. If you make the comment as answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look closely at the statement...

```
HasForeignKey(x => x.Id)
```

...you'll see that `x` is not a `Category` but a `Post`. So it's trying to use `Post`'s primary key as foreign key pointing to `Category`. This is a valid configuration, but only in 1-1 associations, hence the somewhat cryptic exception message.

This is what you're after:

```
public class Post
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    public virtual Category Category { get; set; }
}

public class Category
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Post> Posts { get; set; }
}

modelBuilder.Entity<Post>()
              .HasRequired(x => x.Category)
              .WithMany(x => x.Posts)
              .HasForeignKey(x => x.CategoryId);
```